# Issue with displaying images in frontend

Tags: python, django, image

## views.py:

```
from PIL import Image

img_list =os.listdir(final_path)
frontend_images = []
for images in img_list:
   frontend_path = final_path+str(images)
   image = Image.open(frontend_path)
   frontend_images.append(image)
   print(frontend_images)    
return render(request,'images.html',{'images':frontend_images})
```

**I am sending the images to the frontend for displaying in frontend**

## images.html

```
{% for img in images %}
<img src='{{img}}'/>
{% endfor %}
```

**Its not displayed in frontend is there other approach to retrieve images from directory and display it in frontend**

Comment: You should make use of static/media files: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/

Comment: The directory is dynamic ill get the directory using form will it work?

Comment: @ChrisBlesson as long as the directory is in your settings.MEDIA_ROOT, yes. And you certainly want to restrict which directories are available don't you ?

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers                                                                                               
 temp                                                                                                                                                 
       ---Folder1/                                                                                                                    
                   ----cluster1                                                                                             
                                ----images will it work for this dir